# Confusion in Variable type int and Byte during Left shift operator

Tags: java, variables, binary, bitwise-operators

In left Shift.... I choose all Variables type are Byte. But there is an error show about incompatible types.

[that is what i'm trying to do in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjle0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, really only `int`, `double`, `float`, `long`, and `boolean` are the true primitives. `short`, `char`, and `byte` are inferior half-non-existent types.

You can create arrays of them (`byte[]` exists), and use them as a type (`byte a;` is legal), but in math operations **there is no such thing as a byte, short, or char**.

Given:

```
byte a = 5;
byte b = 10;
```

The expression `a + b` is of type int. As in, if you try this stunt:

```
public void test(int a) {
  System.out.println("The int variant");
}

public void test(byte a) {
  System.out.println("The byte variant");
}

byte x = 5;
byte y = 10;
test(x + y);
```

You would see... "The int variant".

To do what you want to do here, add casts to `byte`: `byte b = (byte) (a << 2);`.

NB: In Bytecode, i.e. the stuff in class files; what `javac` makes for you, bytes, booleans, shorts, and floats do not exist at all. There's `DADD`, `FADD`, `IADD`, and `LADD` (for double/float/int/long respectively). There are no short, char, or byte variants.

The reason is fairly simple: Given that CPUs when java was created were almost all at least 32-bit (and in fact, today, almost all are 64-bit), you gain absolutely nothing whatsoever by using fewer bits; if anything, it would be *slower*, not faster.

Java 'correctly' packs byte arrays (each entry in a byte array only takes 8 bits, not more). That's the only time where '... but bytes are small!' is relevant, and java does the correct thing there.